# Custom Nginx conf not reflecting in uwsgi-nginx docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, uwsgi

I have build a dockerfile. My custom nginx conf (`nginx.conf`) is in root directory

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.8-alpine

RUN apk add py3-setuptools
RUN apk add python3-dev

RUN apk add gcc
RUN apk add g++

RUN apk add --no-cache libressl-dev curl-dev musl-dev libffi-dev make

ARG env

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./pip_req.txt /app
RUN pip install -r /app/pip_req.txt

COPY ./ /app

ENV UWSGI_INI /app/deployment/$env/uwsgi.ini

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


COPY deployment/$env/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.d/app.ini
COPY deployment/$env/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

On docker image deployment, I get default content in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

If I copy nginx.conf with another name, file copies correctly, But i am not sure which conf is being used as both conf use same listen port.

Answer (score 0):

[The image you're using](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx) has [a custom entrypoint script](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker/blob/master/docker-images/entrypoint.sh) that completely rewrites the Nginx configuration at startup time.  There is some minimal ability to customize it through environment variables, or it looks like if you have an `/app/nginx.conf` file that gets copied to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and other files are left unmodified.  If you do have other files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, they're documented to be used in addition to this default generated documentation.

This image's setup to run two separate processes in a single container isn't generally considered a Docker best practice.  You also might consider running a custom image based on the standard `python` image and a separate `nginx` proxy container, maybe using Docker Compose to launch them together.  The standard `nginx` image has a fixed default configuration that can be overridden much more normally (either `COPY`ing it into a derived image or with a bind mount); the only particular special setup it has is the ability to replace environment variables.